# Unescape html to display properly in view

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I insert data into the db I use html_escape($var); to escape my data. The data looks like the following:

```
In de k<strike>oud</strike>e winter van 1956, op 20 januari, werd Lea geboren als eerste kind. Haar eerste levenservaringen speelden zich af in een slagersfamilie. Het sprookje “Ze leefden lang en gelukkig” was niet helemaal op haar lijf geschreven, bleek algauw. Na het overlijden van Lea’s ouders werd ze warm ontvangen bij de familie De Pillecyn en als pleegkinderen in de familiekring opgenomen. In de tijdspanne van 1973-1974 studeerde Lea verpleegkunde aan het Provinciaal Instituut voor te Gent. In 1977 trad Lea in de huwelijks-vaarwateren en tussen 1979 en 1982 werden haar zoon en dochter geboren<span style="color:rgb(0,255,255);">.Dit is een zin.</span><br>
```

Mind the "strike" and "color span" at the end.

When I load this on the view it looks like this?

http://d.pr/i/HHwq

Is there a function to "unescape" this. I allready tried urldecode etc, but that doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Post the relevant code you use to insert the data into the db which is probably where you need to fix it.

Comment: If you mean `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`, you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode` or `htmlentities_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother to "escape" it in the first place?

Your database text column can handle html tags, and you are only complicating your work by making them into html entities before saving.

Comment: When i push it to the database without escaping this error is thrown: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'color:rgb(255,242,204);">This is a test.", bio.content = "Er verliepe' at line 1 So it crashes everytime i use color. @MightyPork

Comment: You should use PDOs and prepared statements, not the old mysql_query. Then you won't get this kind of errors.